# how can I upload a file to sharepoint using vba?

Tags: sharepoint-online, vba

Update, I've learned that the SharedWorkSpace object has been deprecated.  Anyone have another solution that doesn't use this object?

I need to write a quick Excel VBA tool to send to our overseas partners so they can upload some big files to our SharePoint site.  I used to be able to do this in older versions of SharePoint using the Office.SharedWorkSpace object, but I no longer have the code and my new attempts have failed to find the right process.  I would share code, but I haven't written any yet that can even compile.  I am able to create the SharedWorkSpace Object, but I can't find any members of that Object that relate to uploading.  Can someone help me get started with some sample code or pointers.  I'm pretty good at figuring things out once I get pointed in the right direction.

Sub UploadFileToSharePoint(stFile as string)

```
 Dim sws as Office.SharedWorkSpace
 
 sws.  ' this shows me the list of members but I can't find any that apply
```

End Sub

I've also searched a lot using the Object Browser.  Maybe this functionality has been deprecated?  Frustrated.

Answer (score 0):

The SharedWorkSpace Object has been deprecated starting with Office 2010.